# What does "protoimasen/prepared beforehand" mean in Romans 9:23?

Tags: word-study, romans

**Romans 9:22-23** ESV

> *22* "What if God, desiring to show his wrath and to make known his power, has endured with much patience vessels of wrath **prepared** for destruction, *23* in order to make known the riches of his glory for vessels of mercy, which he has **prepared beforehand** for glory-". [My emphasis] v22 prepared/*katertismena*; v23 prepared beforehand/*proetoimasen*.

There are different ways of looking at *proetoimasen* and all insights welcome. One aspect is that Paul has just used *katertismena* so why does he not repeat it but instead uses a similar but contrasting *proetoimasen*?

Is there a contrast here in the extent of the preparation?

"Prepared beforehand" - before what?

What is the effect of *proetoimasen* being used in Romans 9:23?

Comment: Without going into Greek, doesn't English suggest the glory vessel has also been prepared, but somewhat earlier?

I suggest it's highly unlikely that 'beforehand' makes any more contribution here than it would to Blue Peter TV or a Fanny Craddock cookery programme, whose hosts made famous the phrase 'Here's one that I/we prepared earlier…'

Either way, isn't 'prepared beforehand' the least contentious part of the passage, and prolly better studied after all the rest has been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Romans 9, verses 22 and 23 comprises two parallel, though antithetical, statements that are constructed very differently from a grammatical and linguistic perspective. The use of two different words of similar meaning, the participle katertismena in v22 and the verb proetoimasen in v23, illustrates this point.

Romans 9:22-23 NKJV (parentheses added)

> <sup>**22**</sup> What if God, wanting to show His wrath and to make His power known,
> endured with much longsuffering the vessels of wrath prepared
> (kataritzo [Strong’s 2675](https://biblehub.com/greek/2675.htm)
> meaning to complete, prepare) for destruction,
>
> <sup>**23**</sup> and that He might make known the riches of His glory on the vessels
> of mercy, which He had prepared beforehand (proetoimazó [Strong’s
> 4282](https://biblehub.com/greek/4282.htm) meaning to prepare before)
> for glory

The OP asks, “What is the effect of proetoimasen being used in Romans 9:23?” The words appear synonymous in context; both are rendered with the word “prepared” in many English translations (e.g., ESV, NIV, NASB, NKJV) – katertismena as “prepared” and proetoimasen as “prepared beforehand.” Despite the similarity in meaning, the use of two different words serves to differentiate the action of katertismena from that of proetoimasen.

Rather than focusing on their definitions, I chose instead to examine the morphological differences between katertismena and proetoimasen, specifically the voice and tense inflections.

*VOICE: Active vs. Passive (or is it Middle?)*

Based on the [interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/romans/9-22.htm) of Rom 9:22, the voice of katertismena can be either middle or passive.

> the vessels of wrath prepared (katertismena Verb - Perfect Middle/Passive
> Participle) for destruction

Vine’s Expository Dictionary interprets katertismena to be middle, meaning that the subject is both the agent and the recipient/experiencer of a verbal action ([Voice: Middle](http://www.bcbsr.com/greek/gvoice.html)). However, according to Daniel Wallace, to interpret katertismena as middle is contrary to the normal use of a perfect participle (Basics of New Testament Syntax, p.183). That katertismena is middle is therefore not certain, but I do prefer Vine’s definition of katertismena and have included it below for reference.

> Vine’s Expository Dictionary
>
> "to make fit, to equip, prepare" (kata, "down," artos, "a joint"), is
> rendered "fitted" in Rom 9:22, of vessels of wrath; here the Middle
> Voice signifies that those referred to "fitted" themselves for
> destruction

Thayer’s Greek Lexicon, on the other hand, identifies the voice of katertismena to be passive with God as the agent of the action.

> Thayer’s Greek Lexicon
>
> of men whose souls God has so constituted that they cannot escape
> destruction (but see Meyer (edited by Weiss) in the place cited),
> Romans 9:22

Even if we allow that katertismena is passive, Thayer’s interpretation is problematic. First, the participial construction is ambiguous with regard to the identity of the agent. Second, there is no mention of souls in the text, and the concept of “vessels” itself suggests that “souls” is not implied.

> Barnes Commentary on Romans 9:22
>
> In this place there is not the semblance of a declaration that "God
> had prepared them, or fitted them for destruction." It is a simple
> declaration that they were in fact suited for it, without making an
> affirmation about the manner in which they became so.

In contrast to the ambiguity of v22, God is the subject of proetoimasen in v23 and, given the active voice, is the express agent of the action. Also worth noting is that of the only two occurrences of proetoimazó in the NT (Rom 9:23 and Eph 2:10), God is the subject/agent in both.

> the vessels of mercy, which He had prepared beforehand (proetoimazó Verb - Aorist
> Indicative Active) for glory

*TENSE: Aorist vs. Perfect Participle*

Whereas the verb proetoimasen is in the aorist, the participle katertismena is in the perfect tense. In addition to their voice inflections, the difference in tense further distinguishes the actions of these verbs. The perfect participle signifies that while the action of katertismena occurred in the past relative to the action of the main verb, there is an ongoing effect that continues in the present. ([Greek Verbs: The Perfect Tense](https://www.blueletterbible.org/resources/grammars/greek/simplified-greek/greek-verbs-pt1.cfm)).

The verb proetoimasen, on the other hand, is in the aorist tense, indicative mood. When the aorist is paired with the indicative, it means that the action of the verb occurred in the past in an absolute sense. In other moods, the aorist indicates aspect rather than time. As a general rule, “Only in the indicative mood does the aorist indicate past time” ([Greek Verb Tenses](https://www.ntgreek.org/learn_nt_greek/inter-tense.htm)).

The “pro” in proetoimasen, meaning beforehand, underscores the fact that the action occurred in past time. The OP asks, “Before what?” Because of the complex sentence structure, it is difficult to answer this question. That said, the “pro”/beforehand suggests that the action of proetoimasen came before those of all the other temporal verbs in vv22-23.

*CONCLUSIONS*

Another important question is whether the vessels of wrath are distinct from the vessels of mercy. If the vessels of wrath and the vessels of mercy are two distinct groups, then it stands to reason that all the vessels cannot belong to any one group. Yet every person without exception is said to have sinned and fallen short of God’s glory (cf Rom 3:9-10, Rom 3:22-23, Rom 5:12, Rom 11:32). To consider them as entirely separate groups is, I believe, contrary to one of the main themes of Romans, which is that God does not show favoritism (cf Rom 2:11, Rom 10:12-13).

Romans 11:32

> For God has committed them all to disobedience, that He might have
> mercy on all.

There is a play on words in the imagery of the vessels. Vessels have both an outside and an inside, the container and what it contains. Men are vessels fitted for wrath; in other words, sin is inherent to our nature (Ro 6:6, 7:23-24). But it is man himself who, in bringing sin into the world, has prepared himself for destruction.

Romans 5:12

> Therefore, just as through one man sin entered the world, and death
> through sin, and thus death spread to all men, because all sinned

But God prepared beforehand for us to become vessels of mercy, that is, vessels capable of holding a spirit and a righteousness that is not our own.

Romans 8:9-10

> <sup>**9**</sup> But you are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit
> of God dwells in you. Now if anyone does not have the Spirit of
> Christ, he is not His. <sup>**10**</sup> And if Christ is in you, the body is dead
> because of sin, but the Spirit is life because of righteousness.

2 Corinthians 4:7

> But we have this treasure in earthen vessels, that the excellence of
> the power may be of God and not of us.

While some questions remain unanswered, Rom 9:22-23 tells us that God planted the seed of our redemption, knowing we would sin. He prepared us for mercy, we who were fitted for sin, who even now may be preparing ourselves for destruction (cf Rom 2:5). While the word proetoimasen may reference a past action, it also anticipates an event that is to come.

Thus another way to conceptualize the OP’s question (“Before what?”) is by asking: For what has God prepared us? Using proetoimasen as a bridge between Rom 9:23 and Eph 2:10, that event is understood to be our rebirth in Christ (cf Rom 6:4, 6:11; 7:5-6). God made us from clay, knowing our natural limitations (cf Ps 103:14). But He also prepared us for great things, even to be through Christ a dwelling place of God.

Ephesians 2:10

> For we are His workmanship, created in Christ Jesus for good works,
> which God prepared beforehand that we should walk in them.

Comment: Also, although it didn't include it in my response, I found Ellicott's commentary on Eph 2:10 to be very insightful ([biblehub.com](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ephesians/2-10.htm)).

Comment: In contrast to your "blurs the distinctions" I tend to read v22-23 in the context of v21 where the potter makes 2 groups out of one lump. For me the "dishonour" group prepare themselves by being true to their potter given natures, but the "honour"  are given by sovereign Potter a different nature to be true to.

Comment: I agree with your point to a large extent. The word "blurs" was used for the very reason that is doesn't completely erase the distinctions between the two groups. That said, that everyone has sinned and been true to their given natures at some point challenges the notion some people were prepared for wrath while others were made for glory.

Comment: Thanks. For me Psalm 46:10 does speak of final outcome "My purpose will be established and I will accomplish all my good pleasure". ie: apodo; we give back an account of our lives.

Comment: Romans 9:21 says the Potter has the power; it does not say how and to what extent He exercises that power. IMO we are looking at a mystery that is beyond human comprehension, that of the coexistence of God's omnipotence and man's free will.

Comment: Your detailed look at morphological differences carries top weight for me. I question your "no distinctions". No distinction yes as all from one lump, but distinction after with those who are not given and those who are "given Me out of the world" John 17:6.  I would be happy to chat omnipotence/free will with you in a chat room.

Comment: The idea of “no distinction” is taken from the broader context of Romans (cf Ro 3:22, 10:12). You wrote, “No distinction yes as all from one lump, but distinction after…”   We are in agreement, I think. The distinction comes after the fulfillment of what God has prepared. While the vessel is the same as the one before, what it contains is now completely different (cf Ro 9:10).

Comment: I acknowledge receipt of your "We are in agreement, I think". Thanks.

Comment: Accepted on the basis of most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *katartizo* means to complete, adjust to perfection, restore to proper working order.  It has to do with bringing together many parts into a whole such as the mending of nets (Matthew 4:21), the framing of the ages (Hebrews 11:3), or being joined in same mindedness (1 Corinthians 1:10).  It speaks not only of the end result but of the process whereby the result is reached.  In verse 22 Paul describes 'vessels' (individual people) 'of wrath' (a difficult word which most likely describes the crossing of a line) who are patiently endured by God as they are 'fitted' (are perfected together as a whole) unto or toward 'destruction' (where exclusion from salvation is a realized fact).

In verse 23 Paul uses a different verb, *etoimazo*, and this verb, while meaning to 'make ready' emphasizes the arrival at readiness rather than the process.  Combined with the preposition *pro*, the verb *proetoimazo* means to make ready or, better, to have already arrived at readiness.  The difference is subtle but it is that a making ready always results in readiness, while a preparation can be aborted or disturbed, and does not necessarily result in readiness.

When applied by Paul to 'vessels preparing for destruction' and 'vessels made ready for glory' one emphasis is that the preparation for destruction can be aborted or disturbed (let's say by a hearing with faith of the gospel) whereas having been made ready for glory is irreversible.

We see Paul speaking of predestination regarding the individual believer's conformity to the image of God's Son (Romans 8:29-30) but, although those outside of Christ are condemned already (John 3:16-21) and are heading towards and might arrive at destruction, they are not referred to as predestined for it.

It is appointed for man once to die and then the judgement (the assessment).  Those in Christ have died already; they are already assessed as vessels fitted for glory because Christ is in them.  Those outside of Christ have yet to die, their assessment is yet future, and until they die they may yet be saved.  Hence the long-suffering of God despite His willingness and ability for wrath (crossing the line into judgement).

Comment: Thanks. Thayer's Greek Lexicon describes katartizo in Rom 9:22 as "of men whose souls God has so constituted that they cannot escape destruction". This appears to me to be in contrast to your "preparation for destruction can be aborted".

Comment: @C.Stroud Yep.  That's the strict calvinistic election /reprobation take on Paul's application of the Greek verb to those particular 'vessels'.  Realistically though the soul of every person is so constituted that they cannot escape destruction, they are condemned already... unless they receive Him (active tense), at which point they are given the power to become children of God.  If the "preparation for destruction" can't be aborted then no one would be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Romans 9 is, historically speaking, extremely controversial, being one of the main sources for Calvin's absolute predestination doctrine; this was fiercely opposed by Arminius.  The debate continues today and this question will not resolve that debate.

Therefore, let us concentrate on the question at hand without adding fuel to that debate.

The two verbs in the OP's question are listed in the table below:

| Verb | καταρτίζω (katartizó) Rom 9:22 | προετοιμάζω (proetoimazó) Rom 9:23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Occurrence | 13 times: Matt 4:21, 21:16, Mark 1:19, Luke 6:40, **Rom 9:22**, 1 Cor 1:10, 2 Cor 13:11, Gal 6:1, 1 Thess 3:10, Heb 10:5, 11:3, 13;21, 1 Peter 5:10 | Twice: **Rom 9:23**, Eph 2:10 |
| BDAG Meaning | 1. to cause to be in a condition to function well, put in order, eg, Matt 4:21, Mark 1:19; // 2. to prepare for a purpose, prepare, make, create, outfit, eg, Heb 11;3, Rom 9:22, Heb 10:5, Matt 21:16, etc. | prepare beforehand; the act is used in the NT only of God, eg, Rom 9:23, Eph 2:10. |
| Verse (BLB) | And what if God, desiring to show the wrath and to make known His power, bore with much patience the vessels of wrath, **having been fitted** for destruction | that He might also make known the riches of His glory upon the vessels of mercy, which He **prepared beforehand** for glory |
| Subject of verb | "Vessels of wrath" = the wicked | "Vessels of mercy" = the righteous |
| What God did | bore with much patience | make known the riches of His glory |
| Destiny | destruction | glory |

Thus we find a contrast between the individual choice of the two groups and the choice of these verbs reflects this:

- God bears with the wicked (the "vessels of wrath") with much patience - pleading with them to repent, because God want all people to repent (1 Peter 3:9) so that all people can come to salvation (Tit 2:11, 1 Tim 2:6, etc).  That is, as Paul says in Rom 11:32, God wants to "show mercy to all".  Thus, God has to prepare the wicked for this dire destiny.
- God wants to glorify the righteous because He has prepared the "riches of glory" for them.

Comment: You say, 'God wants to "show mercy to all". ESV Rom 11:32 'that he may have mercy on all'. "may have mercy"; the possibility of mercy exists because [11:32] "God has consigned all to disobedience". Where do you get "wants to" from please, I can't find it in any translation.

Comment: @C.Stroud - as quoted in my answer - see rom 11:32 - "mercy to all".

Answer (score 1):

Here’s some additional perspective. Paul’s choice of words in this verse depends entirely on the context of his response against several unstated arguments. We can try to infer what these arguments were, for which Paul builds a case using bloodline and an analogy of a potter who makes vessels for a house.
Here are some possible arguments presented to Paul that he addresses here:

•   God is unjust in that God *knowingly* created some people for destruction.

•   God arbitrarily has mercy on some and hardens others, so God is unjust in condemning the wicked since no one is able to resist God’s will.

•   God only chooses to save those few *worthy* people who are fundamentally good in nature.

•   The Jews rejected Christ as a group, so they have become ineligible for salvation, which is now available only for gentiles from now on.

•   (Some other argument that I likely missed.)

Part of the controversy has to do with time. We tend to make temporal assumptions and judgments, whereas God, who created space and time, is not constrained by space and time. God knows the beginning and the end of everything—all the free-will choices we have made, are making, and will make.

The eternal I AM can see all of our choices and consequences simultaneously in an eternal present, yet we’re instructed to pray that “Thy will be done,” indicating that God's will is *not* necessarily a foregone conclusion, the exception being prophetic events.

ADDENDUM
One consideration that I missed earlier was to consider how Paul uses the same analogy elsewhere in his writings. In this case, it's in a letter to Timothy.

> Therefore, **if anyone cleanses himself from what is dishonorable**, he
> will be a vessel for honorable use, set apart as holy, useful to the
> master of the house, ready for every good work. So flee youthful
> passions and pursue righteousness, faith, love, and peace, along with
> those who call on the Lord from a pure heart. Have nothing to do with
> foolish, ignorant controversies; you know that they breed quarrels.
> -- 2 Timothy 2:21-23 (ESV)

This is Paul's prescription for being "a vessel of mercy" rather than "a vessel of wrath." What is my vessel filled with? Is my vessel filled with what is dishonorable? If so, Paul instructs me to (1) Flee youthful lusts,  (2) Pursue righteousness, and (3) avoid foolish, ignorant controversies!

Comment: You say that praying "Thy will be done" indicates God's will is not necessarily a forgone conclusion. If one believes God's will is always done then praying "Thy will be done" is an expression of submission to that will. In Luke 22:22 Jesus "goes as it has been determined". For Jesus to be determined to go to the cross would not all the human actions, inc' Adam and Eve's, also need to be determined?

Comment: To answer your question, the full verse in Luke 22:22 (ESV) reads "For the Son of Man goes as it has been determined, **but woe to that man by whom he is betrayed**!” Sounds to me like the betrayer wasn't predetermined, otherwise why would Jesus have added the second half of this verse? This is why I stated the exception that the things written in prophecy have indeed been predetermined. Obviously, not everyone will agree to this interpretation, but I hope it helps explain my perspective.

Comment: Thanks. My perspective is that Judas' actions were determined but a warning is sounded out, "woe" [look out], just because they were determined does not let him off being judged for having done them.

Comment: Let me just note that in my original field of study (physics), there’s been a similar fierce debate between those who still believe in *materialistic determinism*, that ALL events in the universe are mechanistically determined all the way back to the big bang without the need or possibility for any god or gods to intervene, versus those who believe in a *probabilistic, information-based reality* as implied by many interpretations of the experimental results involving quantum mechanics. There's also something called *chaos theory* which is arguably *both* deterministic and probabilistic.